# how does the Angular Js handle data binding with view and event triggered with controller?

Tags: angularjs

If a ng-model changed in View, the $scope will be updated correspondingly, but if there is a {{x()}} in the View and a $scope.x=function(){} in the js part, is it that when any event or stuff happens in the view, the x() will be triggered?

I am not quite clear about the principle of AngularJs' event and functioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the times Angular will properly handle $scope.x=function(){} and update views automatically.

That's because there are only a few moments in application execution time when your code is executed such as page load, AJAX callback etc. Angular knows about such moments and does dirty checking (comparing scope values before and after).

However, there might be times when Angular doesn't aware that you updating scope properties, for example when you integrating with some 3rd party plugins. In such cases you need to wrap your code, which changes scope properties in $scope.$apply method:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.x = function(){};
});
```

Comment: TY for quick reply. Let's say this situation, when the value binding with a ng-model <input> changes, it seems the angular will check all the functions in controller and find out the specified method x() and run it, but others are also executed at the same time. This means there are more than two moments you mentioned that angular will check all related controllers

Comment: When input value changes Angular will update bound scope property itself (without calling your $scope.x = function(){} function). Additionally you can listen to scope property change event and update other properties like $scope.$watch('x', function(){$scope.y = ...});